# is it possible to change Button text color in c++ cx metro app?

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, c++-cx

I have the following XAML code

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name = "Btn1" Click = "Button_Click">
```

can i change the color of the font in the Button_Click method or anywhere else in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can change the color of the button any where in the code

Here's a sample button and a sample code to change color in it's click event

Heres the code to change the color in the click event of the btnChangeFontColor

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btnChangeFontColor.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it by the following code runs in `directX 2013`:

```
void App2::DirectXPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e) {
    bt->Foreground = ref new SolidColorBrush(Windows::UI::Colors::Blue);
}
```

Comment: If possible, please try and explain how this helps the OP and make this a great answer.

Comment: Sorry , what do you mean by OP

Comment: The Original Poster in this case.